# Google API distance matrix with coordinates

Tags: java, google-maps

I am trying to write a code that would fetch destination between two physical points. My request string look like this:

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins="+initial[0]+"|"+initial[1]+"&destinations="+destination[0]+"|"+destination[1]+"&key="+api_key;
```

As a link it looks like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=42.9814292|-70.9477546&destinations=51.5073509|-0.1277583&key=
```

The JSON response is

```
    {
       "destination_addresses" : [ "", "" ],
       "origin_addresses" : [ "", "" ],
       "rows" : [
          {
             "elements" : [
                {
                   "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
                },
                {
                   "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "elements" : [
                {
                   "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
                },
                {
                   "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
                }
             ]
          }
       ],
       "status" : "OK"
    }
```

When tried without "|" the response is

```
    {
   "destination_addresses" : [ "51.5073509,-0.1277583" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "42.9814292,-70.9477546" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Where exactly is the problem? I know that it has to be the coordinates and how i put them into url but I don't understand what I have to change.

Comment: You can't drive from London, England (51.5073509,-0.1277583) to New Hamphire, USA (42.9814292,-70.9477546)

Answer (score 2):

1) Your request is using a `|` pipe character rather than a `,` comma to separate the lat/lngs. Using a pipe instead of a comma is passing four origin/destinations as single number queries rather than two. You have to use the comma between the latitude and longitude

2) The [supported travel modes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#travel_modes) for the Distance Matrix API are driving, transit, bicycling, and walking to get travel distances. However, the coordinates you are using correspond to the following locations:

Origin 42.9814292,-70.9477546 = 130 Water St, Exeter, NH 03833, USA

Destination 51.5073509,-0.1277583 = A4, London WC2N 5DU, UK

None of those modes will be able to give travel distances from the US to the UK, and flight mode is not a supported mode.

Please review the
[Distance Matrix API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro)

If you are just trying to get the absolute distance between those two lat/lngs with the Google Maps APIs, you may need to look into using [`computeDistanceBetween()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance) function in the Geometry library in the Javascript API

[Simple JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xiduyutaja/edit?html,output) adapted from [Google's Navigation functions example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geometry-headings)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Distance between two points</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>    
    <script>
      // This example requires the Geometry library. Include the libraries=geometry
      // parameter when you first load the API. For example:
      // <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry">

      var marker1, marker2;
      var poly, geodesicPoly;

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: {lat: 34, lng: -40.605}
        });

        marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,

          position: {lat: 42.9814292, lng: -70.9477546}
        });

        marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,

          position: {lat: 51.5073509, lng: -0.1277583}
        });

        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition());
        map.fitBounds(bounds);

        poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          map: map,
        });

        geodesicPoly = new google.maps.Polyline({
          strokeColor: '#CC0099',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 3,
          geodesic: true,
          map: map
        });

        var path = [marker1.getPosition(), marker2.getPosition()];
        poly.setPath(path);
        geodesicPoly.setPath(path);
        var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(path[0], path[1]);
        var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(path[0], path[1]);
        var midpoint = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(path[0], path[1], 0.5);
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: "Distance: " + distance/1000 + " kilometers",
          position: midpoint
        });
        infoWindow.open(map);
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&libraries=geometry&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```